# Should I change Debian repository after dist-upgrade?

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

When I installed Debian, it was Debian 7.0 with the Debian wheezy repository.
After these commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

this command shows me Debian 8.2

```
sudo cat /etc/debian_version
```

This is my current `sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
```

And

```
sudo cat /etc/debian_version 
8.2
```

So I should edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

Should I change the wheezy repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to jessie repository?

Answer (score 3):

If you did your upgrade using the repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then you probably don't have a wheezy repository in there - you had a stable repository.

You see, in /etc/apt/sources.list you can put the repositories using codenames ('wheezy', 'jessie', 'sid'...) or you can address the repositories as 'stable', 'testing', 'unstable'. During the lifetime of a Debian release, there is no difference.

But when a new stable version is released, then those associations change. 
If you had 'wheezy' in you 'sources.list' then you still have 'wheezy'. But if you had 'stable' then suddenly your 'stable'-repository points to 'jessie'.

Since something changed your `/etc/debian_version` to the jessie version you are probably using a repository for jessie. And since you apparently didn't change your repository, it is most likely that it points to stable.

**Update**

In your `/etc/apt/sources.list` all the repositories should use the same method - either all use codenames (wheezy, jessie, etc.) or stable/testing/unstable. So you can be sure, that all repositories will alway point to the same release. Otherwise you might end with using "jessie" but only receiving security updates for "wheezy".